# Adding controls dynamically not XHTML formatted

Tags: c#-3.0, asp.net-3.5, xhtml

I'm adding generic html controls to repeater items at "onitemdatabound". It works absolutely fine but just wondering (or hoping) if there's any way of getting those controls to render on the page in XHTML format?

It's just an annoyance really - my markup is beautifully clean and correctly indented **until** the repeater!

Using .net 3.5, and C#.

Thanks in advance, Rob

Answer (score 0):

You could try creating your own XHTML control set that extend what's currently there but have it render using the markup you want. As for the indentation, not sure about that.

Comment: Could also use user controls and add those dynamically (little more control over markup here) - but just hoping there was a simple command to format dynamically added HTML at run time - have looked into it further and I'm beginning to think I'm looking for something that doesn't exist!